# Include multiple nested entity levels in LINQ expression

Tags: c#, linq

I have this LINQ query to get the entities in a hierarchy like Courses -> Modules -> Chapters -> Paragraphs:

```
Course course = db.Courses
                .Include(i => i.Modules.Select(s => s.Chapters));
```

How do I "include" the Pharagraphs in my LINQ query?

Answer (score 0):

```
Course course = db.Courses.Include("Modules.Chapters.Paragraphs");
```

Warning: This may lead to performance problems if the resultset is too big!